# Point location And Distance between two 3D skew lines

Tags: geometry

I have read this forum post

[**Location** of shortest distance between two skew lines in 3D?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1414285/location-of-shortest-distance-between-two-skew-lines-in-3d)

multiple times but I'm stuck.

I have two lines defined resp. by

Point $P_1 (2,4,0)$ and vector $V_1 [2,-2,4]$

Point $P_2 (4,4,1)$ and vector $V_2 [-3,4,-2]$

Step 1) Define the normal vector to the two Vectors
$V_3 = V_1 \times V_2 = [12,8,-2].$

Step 2) Define the Vector
$V_4 = P_2-P_1 = [2,0,1].$

Step 3) Define the abs(Dot Product) : $|V_3.V_4| = 22.$

Step 4) Define the norm : 
$|[V_3]| = \sqrt{12^2+8^2+2^2} = 14.56$

Step 5) Divide abs(Dot Product ) / $|[V_3]|$

Conclusion : Minimum Distance = $ 22/14.56 = 1.51.$

This is correct but how do I get the location of the two points realizing this minimum distance using my example values step by step ?

Thanks in advance Marc

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: This is relatively unreadable. Please typeset using MathJax.

Comment: Out of these calculations, you cannot get the location of the points achieving the smallest distance. See for that the third answer to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1993953

Comment: I have tried to modify your text, which is incorrect mathematically at some places : a point is not "on" a vector : instead, you say that a 3D line is defined by "a point **and** a vector"